# How to reference a Custom Control defined in the same .aspx file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, custom-controls

I have an `.aspx` page with inline code. I need to create derived control and use it in its markup code. I attempted to use `<%@ Register Src="webform1.aspx"   TagPrefix="wad" TagName="CustLabel"   %>` and `<wad:CustLabel ID="mylab" runat="server"  />` but it doesn't work. What should I use instead?

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" %>
<%--<%@ Register Src="webform1.aspx"   TagPrefix="wad" TagName="CustLabel"   %>--%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script runat="server" >

    Public Class CustLabel
        Inherits Label
    End Class

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim a = New CustLabel
        MyLabel.Text = "Hello"
        ' mylab.Text = "j"
    End Sub
</script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <asp:Label ID="MyLabel" runat="server"  />
     <%-- <wad:CustLabel ID="mylab" runat="server"  />--%>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Note**
Code example is in VB but I suppose that the solution is not language dependent.
I think that it is possible to create a CustLabel instance and add it to form1 controls but I need to use it in markup.
I need to have everything in one page because I am creating a website diagnostic page and I want installation be as simple as possible.
In reality I need to derive from `GridView`. I am using  `Label` for the example simplicity.

Comment: A user control has the extention .ascx, but you are using .aspx? When you say it dosent work, are you receving an error?

Comment: @lucidgold It is not a **user** control (.ascx) but a **custom** control. The error message is `Circular file references are not allowed`.

Comment: Oh, could you show more code? Custom control .aspx?

Comment: There is no more code `Public Class CustLabel` is the cutom control I need in this example.